# Maven quarkus project doesn't start anymore after upgrade to 2.7.3 or 2.7.4

Tags: openapi, quarkus, smallrye

After upgrade from 2.7.2 to 2.7.3 or 2.7.4 my quarkus project doesn't start anymore. I get following Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_PRIVATE_NETWORK
at io.vertx.core.http.HttpHeaders.<clinit>(HttpHeaders.java:106)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.headers.HeadersMultiMap.<clinit>(HeadersMultiMap.java:63)
at io.quarkus.smallrye.openapi.runtime.OpenApiHandler.<clinit>(OpenApiHandler.java:24)
at io.quarkus.smallrye.openapi.runtime.OpenApiRecorder.handler(OpenApiRecorder.java:35)
```

Maybe it is releated to the upgrade of open api https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/23886

When I disable open api it starts

```
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.enable=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was caused by a dependency with an older version of netty.

Updating netty fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71185321/can-we-add-access-control-allow-private-network-header-to-iis-cors-module-respon), So i believe we have 2 workarounds:

First try using different browser than chrome (if you don't, go directly to second step)

Then, try enabling CORS in your application.properties like following :

```
quarkus.http.cors=true
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that too, but my problem was an outdated dependency. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71423882/9651670

Thanks, this answer helped me a lot. I had to force a specific netty version on a previous update for azure/microsoft libs to work. Now they work with default managed version from quarkus and i removed netty-bom from dependencymanagement instead of updating it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Difference was updating the dependency and propably run in the problem again vs. removing the own handling of version for netty and let quarkus handle the version and maybe be safe forever :)